# how to reference the Default Recipients set in Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

I'm using jenkins emailext plugin, in the Jenkins global configuration UI, under `Extended E-mail Notification` section, I can set `Default Recipients` to be a list of recipients.

My question is, inside my Jenkinsfile, when I use emailext() step, how can I reference `Default Recipients` set in the UI, because the `to` argument for the step only seems to take a String.

Answer (score 3):

In the help message for the 'Default Recepients' options of the 'Extended E-mail Notification' plugin found in the Jenkins global configuration, one can find the not so clear statement:

> Customize the default recipient list of the email notifications. The plugin will use this list if none is overridden in the project configuration. You may use the $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS token in projects to include this default list, as well as add new addresses at the project level. To CC or BCC someone instead of putting them in the To list, add cc: or bcc: before the email address (e.g., cc:someone@example.com, bcc:bob@example.com).

Taking a best guess how this could work I gave the following a try - and it worked:

```
emailext body: '', to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS', subject: 'To default recepient list'
```

Be careful not to use double quotes for the `to:` argument as groovy would jump in and try to replace it with the value of a variable called `DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS`.

What apparently doesn't work is leaving out the `to:` arguments. It'll just say that the list of recipients is empty.

Comment: is there a way to set up multiple email list? it makes no sense to me why there is just one when different job may require different sets of emails.

Comment: You have different choices to whom to send those mails. Please check the extenden E-Mail notificiation plugin documentation: https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/
The example above (and the question) was about how to use the default recipients as defined in the global Jenkins configuration.
If you don't want the default, you can just use any DL as required.